# onBackPressedDispatcher breaks Jetpack Compose Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, jetpack-compose-navigation

I've found a bug when using **onBackPressedDispatcher** in a Jetpack compose app.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate the bug.
Imagine that the app has the following setup:

- It has one **MainActivity** that has **MainFragment** inside
- **MainFragment** contains a **NavGraph** implemented in Jetpack Compose
- Nav Graph has 3 Composable screens

in **MainActivity** `onCreate` method I have the following line:

`onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback)`

For custom handling of application wide backstack

With this setup navigation back and forth **works correctly**. However, if you **bring the activity to onPause** state (e.g. by clicking on the device home button and opening the app again) **Jetpack Compose navigation somehow breaks** and it defaults to the activity navigation implemented with **onBackPressedDispatcher** instead of composable screens navigation.

In the following video you can see:

1. I can navigate forth and back correctly
2. Once I click the home button and open the app again navigation back breaks. I can no longer go back

[image]

I've published this demo project on GitHub, so you can check it out yourself: https://github.com/konnovdev/NavigationBugDemo/tree/main

I've tried moving **onBackPressedDispatcher** subscription to different lifecycle callbacks inside of activity but it didn't make any difference. Note that in this particular app example **onBackPressedDispatcher** looks redundant as there is only one composable nav graph that has its own navigation handling, but in my real app I do rely on this mechanism.

Am I missing something here? I'm confused why is onPause state breaks the navigation. And I'm not able to find a good workaround for this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update, best fix, remove "this" from OnBackpressCallback

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(onBackPressedCallback)
```

fix (old)

connected fragment navcontroller and mainactivity navcontroller to handleOnBackPressed properly, through a sharedviewmodel.

https://github.com/konnovdev/NavigationBugDemo/pull/1/commits/971e0ec5b5d9589f54bc78559bbe62eaf3d0eede

```
    private val onBackPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        if (!navController.navigateUp()) {
            println("No more back navigation, can exit app or do any other task")
            finish() // Close the app or replace with custom back press handling
        }
    }
```

and in oncreate

```
        sharedViewModel.navController.observe(this) { controller ->
           navController = controller
           // Setup back press callback with NavController

           onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback)
        }
```

viewmodel

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _navController = MutableLiveData<NavController>()
    val navController: LiveData<NavController> = _navController

    fun setNavController(controller: NavController) {
        _navController.value = controller
    }
}
```

and in fragment, setNavController

```
 NavigationBugDemoTheme {
     val navController = rememberNavController()
     sharedViewModel.setNavController(navController)
     //rest of the code
```

Comment: thank you! The fix with removing "this" from OnBackpressCallback works! So I'll use this solution. One thing to add is with this fix I would need to make sure i remove the back pressed listener when my activity lifecycle ends, as it states in the official documentation: "It is expected that you call OnBackPressedCallback.remove to manually remove your callback."